# can't connect to mongo shell seems iptables related

Tags: mongodb, firewall, iptables

Just installed mongodb on centos 6. trying to connect to mongo sh with command "mongo" but got this error message:
2015-09-26T07:07:35.309+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2015-09-26T07:07:35.316+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179

however, once i stop my firewall (iptables stop) i can access mongo shell
here is my iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:28017 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:27017 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
LOGGING    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:51396 
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1           tcp spt:27017 state ESTABLISHED 

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `IPTables-Dropped: ' 
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Searched and tried different solutions.
remove lock, repair; reset iptables, nothing helps.

These are the iptables's log of dropping packets

Sep 26 06:59:38 xxx kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27017 DPT=51396 WINDOW=32768 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0

Sep 26 07:04:47 xxx kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=27017 DPT=59830 WINDOW=32768 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0

can't figure why its still blocking 27017.

Answer (score 0):

Open  Port (27017) in Firewall.